# How to get permission to access all files on MacOS

Tags: macos, permissions, filesystems, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

I developed an app for MacOS, it allows users to manage all files of his computer.

I found the entitlement key:

```
com.apple.security.files.all
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_files_all?language=objc

but it is Deprecated.

I switched to another method:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/</string>
</array>
```

it basically meet my needs, although the experience is not very good. But unfortunately, Apple thinks this is inappropriate. Here's Apple's reply:

> We've determined that one or more temporary entitlement exceptions
> requested for this app are not appropriate and will not be granted:
>
> com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write
>
> /
>
> We understand this may prevent the app from being approved for the Mac
> App Store. We encourage you to investigate other ways of implementing
> the desired functionality.

Do you have any good way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this entitlement
`com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write`

And ask the user for permisson with a NSOpenPanel and store the URL with a security scope to use on subsequent launch of your app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference/asset/media-rep/bookmark/enabling_security-scoped_bookmark_and_url_access/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_files_user-selected_read-write